# How to place a Label after f.text_field?

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello i want to place a "€" sign after the text_field but the rails form automaticaly does a < . br >. Help me please

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@composto) do |f| %>

<%= f.text_field :nome %>

<%= f.text_field :preco %> 
 <%= f.submit "Gravar" %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Just put the **€** after the text field                                                        `<%= f.text_field :preco, :id => "preco2", :label => "Preço"  %> €`    I haven't seen rails put a `<br />` automatically

Comment: first thing i tried lol it places the "€" before the next input and not on front :(

Comment: Could you paste the snippet for the `form_for`

Comment: That is not the entire `form_for`. I meant from the `bootstrap_form_for` to its `end`

Comment: Still I cant find the `text_field` in the `form_for`. I don't understand after reading the code. It is not the complete `form_for` still. I wont understand till I have seen the line that is causing the problem inside the `form`

Comment: It was really confusing... i simplified it i want the text_field to end up with a "€" sign but if i do : 
<%= f.text_field :preco %>  €

the € will be before the submit button and not after the :preco text_field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `bootstrap_form_for` inserts the code for its form. So you will have to change some `css`.

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@composto) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :nome %>
  <%= f.text_field :preco, class: 'inline-class' %><span class="symbol-left">€</span>
  <%= f.submit "Gravar" %>
<% end %>
```

Now in your css file, preferably `application.css` (otherwise you will have to give `!important` to each css tag.

```
.form-control { width: 95%; }
.inline-class { display: inline; }
.form-group { display: inline; }
.control-label { display: block; }
.symbol-left { display: inline; }
```

This is probably not the proper way. But this works.

Comment: indeed it does! Thank you for your help! :))))))